# texture stretched

Tags: texturing

made 1 model after duplicate remove doubles then delete the edges in center. it would make the texture stretch, i delete edges to reduce poly count but texture stretched , how to do it without texture stretch out.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your model you want to make sure that you have properly applied the UV's for your model. Add seams to areas where it's needed and then unwrap the model each time you make changes to see the final result. verify that the UV's aren't stretching where they shouldn't. You can use the stretch tool to assist with this.

[image]

The darker the blue the cleaner the final result will be.